# what is difference between Kinesis Streams and Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Firehose is fully managed  whereas Streams is manually managed.

If other people are aware of other major differences, please add them. I'm just learning.
Thanks..

Answer (score 11):

**Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose** can send data to:

- Amazon S3
- Amazon Redshift
- Amazon Elasticsearch Service
- Splunk

To do the same thing with **Amazon Kinesis Data Streams**, you would need to write an application that consumes data from the stream and then connects to the destination to store data.

So, think of Firehose as a *pre-configured streaming application with a few specific options*. Anything outside of those options would require you to write your own code.

Comment: @BrunoNegrãoZica Please create a new question rather than asking on a comment attached to an old question.